# How to create objects of generic types in flutter/dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How can we create object of generic types in dart?

For my use case, each of my api responses are wrapped as `ApiResponse` class. For login api response, I get a json object such as

```
{
    "data": {
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "name": "A"
    },
    "message": "Successful",
    "status": true
}
```

So to parse these responses, I created classes as below, but they throw compile time error stating that **The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'Type'.** :

```
class ApiResponse<T extends BaseResponse> {
  bool status;
  String message;
  T data;

  ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
    data = T.fromJson(json['data']);  // <<<------- here is the compile time error
  }
}

abstract class BaseResponse {
  BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}

class Login extends BaseResponse {
  String name, email;

  Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : super.fromJson(json) {
    name = json['name'];
    email = json['email'];
  }
}

// and I want to use it like below
usage() {
  ApiResponse<Login> a = ApiResponse.fromJson({});
  String name = a.data.name;
}
```

Can anyone help me fix the error?

Comment: Umm, usually you don't call methods on a type right? I wonder if your intent is to do `data = data.fromJson(json['data'])`

Comment: We get this error if we use `data = data.fromJson(json['data'])` ::

main.dart:9:17:
Error: The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'BaseResponse'.
 - 'BaseResponse' is from 'main.dart'.
    data = data.fromJson(json['data']);
                ^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.

Comment: @JainamJhaveri did you solve this? please help me by answering the question

Comment: Haven't managed to solve this

Comment: You can't inherit constructors in Dart. You can only inherit instance members.

Answer (score 3):

ok let's add a little hack to manage your use case:

- let say that you have two responses `Login` and `Error` both of Type `BaseResponse`

```dart
abstract class BaseResponse {}

class Login extends BaseResponse {
  Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {}
}

class Error extends BaseResponse {
  Error.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {}
}
```

- the trick is that you will decide the type of `BaseResponse` at `ApiResponse` constructor like this

```dart
class ApiResponse<T extends BaseResponse> {
  T data;

  ApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = _getProperDataValue<T>(json['data']);
  }

  static E _getProperDataValue<E extends BaseResponse>(
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    switch (E) {
      case Login:
        return Login.fromJson(jsonData) as E;
      case Error:
        return Error.fromJson(jsonData) as E;
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError('Not Supported Type');
    }
  }
}
```

- both responses will work

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final loginRes = ApiResponse<Login>.fromJson(<String, dynamic>{
    'data': <String, dynamic>{},
  });
 final errorRes = ApiResponse<Error>.fromJson(<String, dynamic>{
    'data': <String, dynamic>{},
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `T` as `BaseResponse` :

```dart
data = (T as BaseResponse).fromJson(json['data']);
```

Comment: We get following error::

```
main.dart:9:32:
Error: The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'BaseResponse'.
 - 'BaseResponse' is from 'main.dart'.
    data = (T as BaseResponse).fromJson(json['data']);
                               ^^^^^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Can you try to use `factory` keyword before `BaseResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);`?

Comment: @AugustinR using factory will also not work